# scrollview stops zooming after dragging once

Tags: swift, scroll, uiscrollview, zooming, avplayer

I have a project where I'm using AVPlayer to reproduce a video which is contained in a UIView inside a scrollview. I need to be able to zoom in and out and drag/scroll, but the zooming stops working right after I drag the video once. I am zooming using the same approach I would use when zooming an ImageView and everything seems to be set properly. I have actually tried many things and I can't seem to find where the issue is coming from. I am setting minimum and maximum zoom scales and also delegates.